# airflow deleting xcom's being detected as zombie job

Tags: python, airflow, orchestration

im new to airflow and wanted to try to create a dag that removes xcoms.
This is my simple code:

```
@dag(
    start_date=datetime(2024, 3, 15),
    schedule_interval='@daily',
    catchup=False
)
def delete_xcom():[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/W9LnA.png)
    @provide_session
    @task(trigger_rule=TriggerRule.ALL_DONE)
    def cleanup_xcom(session=None):
        session.query(XCom).filter(XCom.dag_id == "delete_xcom").delete()


    cleanup_xcom()
delete_xcom()
```

but the task keep failing and this is the log:

```
[2024-03-16, 20:38:21 IST] {standard_task_runner.py:107} ERROR - Failed to execute job 203 for task cleanup_xcom ((sqlite3.OperationalError) database is locked
[SQL: INSERT INTO log (dttm, dag_id, task_id, map_index, event, execution_date, owner, owner_display_name, extra) VALUES (?, ?, ?, ?, ?, ?, ?, ?, ?)]
[parameters: ('2024-03-16 18:38:16.535825', 'delete_xcom', 'cleanup_xcom', -1, <TaskInstanceState.SUCCESS: 'success'>, '2024-03-16 18:38:13.928078', 'airflow', None, None)]
(Background on this error at: https://sqlalche.me/e/14/e3q8); 757)
[2024-03-16, 20:38:21 IST] {local_task_job_runner.py:234} INFO - Task exited with return code 1
[2024-03-16, 20:38:21 IST] {taskinstance.py:3312} INFO - 0 downstream tasks scheduled from follow-on schedule check
[2024-03-16, 20:38:22 IST] {scheduler_job_runner.py:1755} ERROR - Detected zombie job: {'full_filepath': '/opt/airflow/dags/delete_xcom.py', 'processor_subdir': '/opt/airflow/dags', 'msg': "{'DAG Id': 'delete_xcom', 'Task Id': 'cleanup_xcom', 'Run Id': 'manual__2024-03-16T18:38:13.928078+00:00', 'Hostname': 'b0c160b98f88'}", 'simple_task_instance': <airflow.models.taskinstance.SimpleTaskInstance object at 0x7f8db16939d0>, 'is_failure_callback': True} (See https://airflow.apache.org/docs/apache-airflow/stable/core-concepts/tasks.html#zombie-undead-tasks)
```

I tried to restart the airflow container, create new dag.
from what iv seen online this code should work.

Answer (score 0):

The error was clear.

> `(sqlite3.OperationalError) database is locked`

Don't use SQLite.
Integrate your airflow with any external `postgres` or `mysql`.

> Airflow Documentation: [Choosing database backend](https://airflow.apache.org/docs/apache-airflow/stable/howto/set-up-database.html#choosing-database-backend)
>
> > By default, Airflow uses SQLite, which is intended for development purposes only.

Comment: It's _possible_ to have multiple processes using sqlite concurrently -- it supports proper range locking and the like -- but the client needs to be willing to participate (blocking until it can grab the necessary locks instead of failing immediately, in this case). Which is to say, this is good advice for this very specific case with airflow, but programs that are better citizens in using sqlite correctly could get away with it as long as the number of concurrent writers is low enough to make contention occasional as opposed to constant.